# Find Highest Value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like so:

```
class1 = {
          max: 10, 3, 5
          Michael: 4. 4, 8
          jack: 0, 0, 3
          }
```

This is the relevant code

```
class1 = {}
        with open("1.txt", "r+") as f:
            for line in f:
                columns = line.split(":")
                if len(columns) == 2:
                    names = columns[0]
                    scores = columns[1].strip()
                else:
                    pass
                if class1.get(names):
                    class1[names].append(scores)
                else:
                    class1[names] = list(scores)
```

The numbers represent the scores and I would like for the highest score for each name to be printed out, this is my desired output:

```
max: 10
Micheal: 8
jack: 3
```

I have already tried this:

```
max_value = max(class1.values())
print(sorted(max_value))
```

But it makes no difference to my output.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: That isn't even a valid dict in python. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: @Racialz, that's my actual dictionary, each key has more than one value

Comment: If those `dict` keys are supposed to be strings you forgot the quote marks. Also, what's with the crazy indentation in your 2nd code block? BTW, the `else: pass` is redundant.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
class1 = {}
with open("1.txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split(":")
        if len(columns) == 2:
            name = columns[0].strip()
            scores = map(int, columns[1].split(','))
            class1[name] = scores

for name, scores in class1.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, max(scores)))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for name, l in class1:
    print("%s : %d" % (name, max(l)))
```